# How can I add one more button on kivy?

Tags: python, button, widget, kivy

This is my code. 
I would like to add one more button which stops the application.
There are two buttons, one is for clear the canvas, and another is to stop the app.
However, if I put both on my program, either of them does not work. If I comment out one, then another starts working. I would like to use both.

```
from random import random
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.graphics import Color, Ellipse, Line


class MyPaintWidget(Widget):

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        color = (random(), 1, 1)
        with self.canvas:
            Color(*color, mode='hsv')
            d = 1.
            Ellipse(pos=(touch.x - d / 2, touch.y - d / 2), size=(d, d))
            touch.ud['line'] = Line(points=(touch.x, touch.y))

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        touch.ud['line'].points += [touch.x, touch.y]


class MyPaintApp(App):

    def build(self):
        parent = Widget()
        self.painter = MyPaintWidget()
        clearbtn = Button(text='Clear')
        clearbtn.bind(on_release=self.clear_canvas)
        parent.add_widget(self.painter)
        parent.add_widget(clearbtn)

        parent = Widget()
        self.painter = MyPaintWidget()
        quitbtn = Button(pos=(100,0),text='quit')
        quitbtn.bind(on_release=self.quit_app)
        parent.add_widget(self.painter)
        parent.add_widget(quitbtn)
        return parent        

    def clear_canvas(self, obj):
        self.painter.canvas.clear()

    def quit_app(self,obj):
        btn1=Button(pos=(width,0),text="QUIT")
        btn1.bind(on_release=self.quit_app)
        App.get_running_app().stop()



if __name__=="__main__":
    MyPaintApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your app's `build` method, `parent` gets overwritten. Change the definition to

```
def build(self):
    parent = Widget()
    self.painter = MyPaintWidget()
    clearbtn = Button(text='Clear')
    clearbtn.bind(on_release=self.clear_canvas)
    parent.add_widget(self.painter)
    parent.add_widget(clearbtn)

    quitbtn = Button(pos=(100,0),text='quit')
    quitbtn.bind(on_release=self.quit_app)
    parent.add_widget(quitbtn)
    return parent
```

for both buttons to be displayed. Also, your `quit_app` callback has two superfluous lines, it should just be

```
def quit_app(self,obj):
    App.get_running_app().stop()
```

Comment: Thanks! Your answer has really helpful!